# Ctrl + Shift + C only triggers language switch

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts

How do I get Linux (preferably, without binding to wm) to wait until all keys in the combination are released before applying it? In my case, it is impossible to `Copy/Paste` text from/into terminal since <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> firstly triggers a language switch and ignores the rest of the combination ('C').

Comment: Which Linux distribution are you using? I tried with Ubuntu 12.04 and it behaves as it should.

Comment: Yep, in Ubuntu it's default behavior - that's why I'm sure about the existence of solution. I'm currently using Arch Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a long time bug reported back in 2004 [here](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=865) (and [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/control-center/+bug/36812)).

As you can check in the previous links there are already patches for this bug, so althoug the problem isn't completely solved (check [this](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=865#c101) comment), and depending on your distribution, your specific problem should be fixed as soon as the patches are pushed upstream.